# Remove line feed after img tag in html

Tags: html, css

I'm using a img tag before a h3 tag, no break statements used. But when I run it in the browser it displays the 2 tags on separate lines. Is there a CSS technique that can fix this or maybe an even easier tag attribute that will make the two elements display on the same line?

Thanks in advance!

------------------------------- edit ----------------------------------------------

The answers so far work well. But it's not there quite yet. If you look at the screenshot you'll see what I want (I should've specified in the first place, i know)...

If I use one of the methods above, you'll see that the h3 tag is not floating in the middle of the img tag. I want the h3 tag to float right in the middle of the image..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why not flexbox? Have you tried using flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use a `line-height` attribute for `h3` which equals to your `img`'s `height`.
2. Use `padding-top`  and `padding-bottom` for to your `h3` and play with it to get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The default style of headline tags (`<h1>` to `<h6>`) contains `display: block`. Giving your `<h3>` tag a style of `display: inline` will override this behavior.

Comment: Works well, but please have a look at my edit to my post above. A little something extra I'm looking for..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in the source code or the actual elements? If you mean the actual elements, add `float: left;` to both of them and they will appear side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

What if you place the `<img>` tag inside the `<h3>` block, e.g.

```
<h3><img src=".." /> Hello world!</h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

While using HTML we face a problem. If we use `<img>` and `<h1>` tags, both will not be on the same line. There is one solution to place them on the same line - 
use `img` tag inside of `h` tag:

```
<h2><img src="">Text here</h2>
```